# Why is my jquery call showing up as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, page-fragments

I'm trying to grab a url from an `<a>` tag and display the first paragraph of the url underneath the title. Currently this returns 'undefined'.

My Html:

```
<section class="community">
<div class="news">
 <ul class="article-list">
  <li><a href="">This is an article</a></li>
  <li><a href="">This is an article</a></li>
  <li><a href="">This is an article</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

My JQuery:

```
var url = $('.community .news ul li a').attr('href .p1'); 
  $.get(url, function(response) {
  $('.community .news ul li').append("<p>" + url + "</p>");
});
```

FYI .p1 is a class surrounding the first paragraph in the url (what I'm trying to display basically)

Comment: `.attr('href .p1')`?

Comment: Keep in mind that `$('.community .news ul li a')` returns a list, not just one item

Comment: @miparnisari , yes I'm trying to do it for every list item... not sure I know what you mean

Comment: @Phil I'lm trying to bring in the .p1 class on page the url directs to

Comment: I mean that you cannot change an attribute of a list of Dom elements. You need to loop over each element.

Comment: You probably want `.attr('href') + ' .p1'` or something like that, I don't use this feature. You're also going to have to iterate over them individually using `each`.

Comment: @TonyWu where would I add that?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks! How do I do each?

Comment: `var url = $('.community .news ul li a .p1').attr('href'); ` and `$('.community .news ul li').append("<p>" + url.toString() + "</p>");` ?

Answer (score 1):

Only `$.load` supports [loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) so with that in mind, try this...

```
$('.community .news ul li a[href]').each(function() {
    $('<p>').insertAfter(this).load(this.href + ' .p1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to simple get your url bu usin below code

**var url = $('.community .news ul li a').attr('href');**

i do not understand why you add " .p1" with href ?

try this code to get url

Comment: Hi,I just did that... and it's bringing stuff in but it's still saying 'undefined'. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I also tried this and it doesn't work.. since I need to load just the first paragraph from that url:

$(".community .news ul li p").load( url + " "  + ".p1");